# Using excel query to get a substring of the xml data from a URL

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

I have the following table in excel where col1=movie ID, col2 = movie name. I'm trying to use excel web query to to get the production firm name of all the movies in my list.

```
ID          Movie Name
tt1540741   A Single Shot (2013)
tt4630158   A Space Program (2015 Documentary)
```

For example 
    http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2330270&tomatoes=true&plot=short&r=xml

The link will return a XML that contains the production firm name.

I'm not sure how to write the excel formula that will achieve this goal.

(I want the output to looks like this)

```
ID          Movie Name                         Production firm
tt1540741   A Single Shot (2013)                      ABC
tt4630158   A Space Program (2015 Documentary)        DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here is my solution. Note that the row numbers are fixed here, you can change it to be dynamic.

Column A here contains all the URL with a unique movie ID. 
For example

http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0811137&tomatoes=true&plot=short&r=xml

```
Sub getMovieInfo()
'  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim x As Integer
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = 1491
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To 1491
     ' Insert your code here.
     pos = "A" & x
     des = "$D" & x
    ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=Cells.Item(x, "A"), _
    ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range(des)
   ' Sheets("Sheet1").Range(des).Value = Cells.Item(x, "A")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))

    If (IsEmpty(Sheets("sheet3").Range(des)) = True) Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
        If (IsEmpty(Sheets("sheet3").Range(des)) = True) Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
  End Sub
```